# RevenueCat SDK (flutter_purchases) not not returning correct thing

Tags: flutter, revenuecat, flutter-in-app-purchase

1st Error I'm Getting is that occasionally (without an obvious reason), RevenueCat SDK will return nothing inside the 'active subscriptions', even thou I am currently subscribed to something.

2nd Error Problem is that the entitlements inside 'getPurchaserInfo()' sometimes return an outdated set of entitlements.

```
 PurchaserInfo userInfo = await Purchases.getPurchaserInfo();

print(userInfo.entitlements.active);

print(userInfo.activeSubscriptions);
```

Note: This is all within sandbox mode.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: @CodeMaster I have added the code to the post.
(Only included the relevant code)